# Light up an LED every time somebody clicks a certain button

Tags: raspberry-pi

My boss wants to light up an LED in the office every time somebody clicks on a certain button on our website.

It should stay lit for maybe 1/10 second - in other words, just blip every time somebody clicks on the button. His vision is to have 1 LED for every customer such that whenever they are using the site, he can see all the activity in an artsy kind of way. I suppose I could start by mocking up a web page with a picture of an LED on it...

But I was thinking of using a Raspberry Pi.  I'd be happy with only 1 LED at first, and then figure out how to do it for multiple customers later.

And would I use sockets to poll for events?
I could do an ajax call every x seconds and find out how many flashes I need to do between now and the next interval.  That would take sockets out of the equation and use a technology that I'm already familiar with.

Comment: does that button on the website do anything else?  anything website specific or just call home?

Comment: Well, the button is only in my mind at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many tutorials on the web on how to light and LED using Raspberry Pi and GPIO ports. [Here](https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/gpio-examples/tux-crossing/gpio-examples-1-a-single-led/) is an example.

In your case it sounds like there is no real-time requirements to blip the LED, i.e. the LED does **not** have to blip immediately after the click. So I think using Ajax to pull periodically is perfectly ok, since you're familiar with that already. It has the small added benefit of batching the blips and thereby reducing network utilization.